# django: bootstrap modal not displaying

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

To test modal creations in python with django I created a test app named `modalTestApp`.
Then I copied [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#live-demo) html that I got off of the bootstrap website and pasted it into the `main.html` inside the app, without changing it. The webpage from the app loads fine but clicking the button to preview the modal does nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

main/base.html:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src={% static "jquery/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" %}></script>
      <script src={% static "jquery/jquery.min.js" %}></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src={% static 'tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js' %}></script>
      <script src={% static "bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/popper.min.js" %}></script>
      <script src={% static "bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .main {
            margin-top: 50px;
            padding: 10px 0px;
        }
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static "bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}>
        <title>{% block title %} {% endblock title %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dar bg-dark pb-0 pr-0">
          <ul class="nav flex-row">
            <p class="navbar-brand mb-0 pt-0" style="color: #eee">Weather Data</p>
            <a href="/", class="nav-link active">Home</a>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a href="/stations", class="nav-link active">Stations</a>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
          {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="/register", class="nav-link active">Register</a>
            <a href="/login", class="nav-link active">Login</a>
          {% else %}
            <a href="/logout", class="nav-link active">logout</a>
            <a href="/users/{{ user.username }}", class="nav-link active">Profile</a>
          {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

main.html:

```html
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
 {%block content %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

EDIT:
console output + webpage preview (same before and after button clicked):
[image]

Comment: Can you add the output of the Browser's console, and about the Bootstrap JS and CSS files, did you add them to the static folder of that application?

Comment: I was getting an error saying `popper.min.js.map` is missing so I changed that `<script>` line to use a cdnjs instead but the problem presists, all the other js and css files load fine. I added the console screenshot in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you do not need to write the script tag, you need to write how it is done in the bootstrap documentation - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

Just as example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You also need to see the django documentation on how to insert static files, this will help you use your pictures, styles, javascript - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Also, just as example

```
settings.py (Root setting)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("static"))]
```

```
urls.py (root urls)

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I have all the static files settings working fine but your answer prompted me to take another look at the "Get Started" page. I copied the bundle script instead of the separate one and now it works!

Comment: You are welcome! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is the template file is not fetching right css and js or may be your directory is not correct. Check my code below its working fine. Thanks

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```